# Prompt Dialog Choice with List object Bot Framework

Tags: c#, .net, bots, botframework

I'm creating a PromptDialog Choice which populates my list of object Options stored in Database. However, it only displayed the type of the Object not the name of the Options. Can anyone suggest me the best way to load Option from the database and binding it with the PromptDialog? Here's what I've tried:

```
private void ShowOptions(IDialogContext context)
{
    List<Option> ListOptions = Option.CreateListOption();
    PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, ListOptions, "Are you looking for a flight or a hotel?", "Not a valid option", 3);
}
private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Option> result)
{
    try
    {

        Option optionSelected = await result;

        switch (optionSelected.Text )
        {
            case "A":
                context.Call(new RootDialog(), this.ResumeAfterChoose);
                break;
            default: { context.Wait(MessageReceiveAsync); break; }
        }
    }
    catch (TooManyAttemptsException ex)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! Too many attemps :(. But don't worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!");

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceiveAsync);
    }
}
```

Here is

```
  [Serializable]

public class Option
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Option()
    {
        ID = 0;
        Text = "";
    }
    public static List<Option> CreateListOption()
    {
        List<Option> list = new List<Option>();
        Option A = new Option();
        A.ID = 1;
        A.Text = "A";
        Option B = new Option();
        B.ID = 2;
        B.Text = "B";
        list.Add(A);
        list.Add(B);
        return list;
    }
}
```

And here's the result I've gotten:

[image]

Comment: Is using List<string> with the Option.Text an option?

Comment: yep..we can do that but i need id and text both in result inside OnOptionSelected() Method  (// Option optionSelected = await result;)

Comment: You could lookup for the id in the OnOptionSelected method using the text result?

Answer (score 0):

The `Choice` static method also contains a `Descriptions` parameter. You could try the following:

- For the options, send a `List<int>` containing your options ids
- For the descriptions, send the options text.

Comment: thanks Ezequiel ...it worked for me but ...i need to send an object..can we send object and receive object containing id and text... i am asking this because i need to send more property in object ....or is there any other way to achieve it that will be great help...

Comment: As I mentioned before, with the ID you could just lookup for the actual option. Another option to try is overriding the ToString() in the Option class. I don't remember what would happen at the selection time if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ezequiel, you can provide the `Descriptions` parameter like:

```
    PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, 
          ListOptions.Select(l=>l.ID).ToArray(),
          "Are you looking for a flight or a hotel?", "Not a valid option", 3,
         descriptions: ListOptions.Select(l=>l.Text).ToArray() );
```

Then change your OnOptionSelected to:

```
    private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<int> result)
    {
        try
        {

            int optionSelected = await result;
            var foundOption = Option.CreateListOption().First(o => o.ID == optionSelected);
//do more with foundOption
            switch (optionSelected)
            {
                case 1:
                    context.Call(new RootDialog(), this.ResumeAfterChoose);
                    break;
                default: { context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync); break; }
            }
        }
        catch (TooManyAttemptsException ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! Too many attemps :(. But don't worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!");

            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
```

[image]